# Using javascript interpreter 'otto', How to read a file in client side

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm having difficulties.

I am implementing logic to read the file, encodes it, and send it to the server.
Currently, the library used as javascript interpreter is using 'otto'.

I imported 'fs'(I know it is Built-in module) like

`var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFileSync('./test.txt', 'utf8');`

but occurred error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`

So I inserted `node: { fs: "empty" }` in webpack.config.js file.
Then compile error is not occurred. But when I called a function that contains `fs.readFileSync`  using cli, occurred error.
`TypeError: 'readFileSync' is not a function`

1. First question: 
   I know that 'otto' is just javascript interpreter. For this reason, when I imported 'fs', is there a failure to find the module?
2. Second question:
   If not, How can I read a file from the clientside and send it to the server?
3. Last question: Using 'otto', It is impossible??

This is my spec.
macOS High Sierra, Webpack 4.9.1, Node.js 8.11.1.

Comment: *"Currently, the library used as javascript interpreter is using 'otto'"* Huh? Your browser has a built-in JavaScript engine (which is likely not just an interpreter), and Node.js has a built-in JavaScript engine (called V8). What is this "otto" thing and why are you using it?

Comment: If you do want to use otto (because this is built into a Go project?) then [motto](https://github.com/ddliu/motto) ("Nodejs module environment in golang") might help. But I've never tried it myself.

Comment: It is being used to call a function by ipc communication between node and client.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please use the "edit" link to add the further necessary information to the question. Remember that we don't know **anything** about what you're doing, so don't make us guess. Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> How to read a file in client side

Since you mention Webpack, I'm assuming the "client side" here is a browser. To read a file from a browser, you use the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). Note that your code cannot specify what file to read; the **user** does that, either by picking a file in an `input type="file"` element, or dragging a file into a drop area. In both cases, you'll get a [`File` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), which you can read using the File API.

You cannot use the `fs` Node.js module in a browser.

Comment: Not used in browsers, It is being used to call a function by ipc communication between node and client.

Comment: @박준호 - Then what does Webpack have to do with anything?

Comment: @박준호 - That doesn't answer my question at all.